# For each row in a t-sql query resultset, get the startdate and enddate and extract months between, then union the results as one list of months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem that I am trying to solve with t-sql but I cant figure it out by myself.

I have a simple query:

```
select StartDate, EndDate
from ProductTable
where Site = 'X' and  Product_ID = '1'
```

The result can look like this (there can be **one or more** rows with start and end dates):

| StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-06-01 | 2019-09-30 |
| 2019-12-01 | 2020-04-30 |
| 2020-11-30 | 2020-12-31 |

What I want to do then is that for each row in this resultset, I want to create a list of months between the dates, on the format "yyyymm",  and then union the result of these lists to one resultset.

So for the 3 rows in the first resultset the first step should give:

**ROW 1**: 201906, 201907, 201908, 201909

**ROW 2**: 201912, 202001, 202002, 202003, 202004

**ROW 3**: 202011, 202012

And the final expected result is then of course:

| Months |
| --- |
| 201906 |
| 201907 |
| 201908 |
| 201909 |
| 201912 |
| 202001 |
| 202002 |
| 202003 |
| 202004 |
| 202011 |
| 202012 |

I have experimented a bit with CTEs and Cursors but I haven't real had any success yet.

Can someone help me out? :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a "Tally" or "Nums" function, this becomes child's play.

```
 SELECT Months = CONVERT(CHAR(6),DATEADD(mm,t.N,StartDate),112)
   FROM dbo.ProductTable
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTally(0,DATEDIFF(mm,StartDate,EndDate))t
  WHERE Site = 'X'
    AND Product_ID = '1'
  ORDER BY Site,Product_ID,Months --Just in case we expand on this later.
;
```

It also consumes 1 read instead of 64 like the rCTE method does, which is also slower than a While Loop.

I know a lot of people don't care about that kind of performance for such small sets of data but that's also how they end up with a slow server due to "Death by a Thousand Cuts".

You can search the web for such a function but I can save you some time by posting the link to the one I use.  I know the author. :D

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally

Comment: I would have thought `EOMONTH` would make more sense

Comment: @Charlieface - I'm always open to different ideas.  How would you use EOMONTH to solve the OP's problem in this case?  We're just counting the number of month boundaries crossed and no other calculations other than DATEDIFF between start and end dates seem necessary to me.  Like I said, though, I'm always willing to learn something new if you'd care to demonstrate.

Comment: Just changing the select to `SELECT Months = EOMONTH(DATEADD(month, t.N, StartDate))` so you get an actual date value, and leave the rest of the code the same. I know OP asked for `201906` etc, but that is not the correct way to store a date. Good answer anyway, have upvoted

Comment: @Charlieface - The other people on this site have taught me not to speculate on doing it "right" by down voting my previous such efforts.  Their mantra seems to be do only what the op asks for even if it's wrong and that's why I didn't make it "right" and gave the op only what they asked for.  I totally agree with you that returning YYYYMM is the wrong way to do this UNLESS it's for display purposes and then doing that in T-SQL is usually (not always) the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Charlieface - Also, I hate end of month dates instead of start of month states and "next period" dates because of the mistakes people make with those.  To your point, just dropping the CONVERT part of the code would produce a real date for the first of the month and NOT be formatted.  Thanks for the positive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE works well to unfold date ranges.

> ```
> ;WITH RCTE_DATES AS (
>    SELECT 
>      DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(StartDate))) AS StartDate
>    , DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(EndDate))) AS EndDate
>    FROM ProductTable
>    WHERE Site = 'X' AND Product_ID = '1'
>
>    UNION ALL
>    
>    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, StartDate), EndDate
>    FROM RCTE_DATES
>    WHERE StartDate < EndDate
> )
> , CTE_YEARMONTHS AS (
>   SELECT DISTINCT
>     YEAR(StartDate)*100+MONTH(StartDate) AS YearMonth
>   FROM RCTE_DATES
> ) 
> SELECT *
> FROM CTE_YEARMONTHS
> ORDER BY YearMonth;
> ```
>
> ```
> | YearMonth |
> | --------: |
> |    201906 |
> |    201907 |
> |    201908 |
> |    201909 |
> |    201912 |
> |    202001 |
> |    202002 |
> |    202003 |
> |    202004 |
> |    202011 |
> |    202012 |
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eb6795b850e79217376f4147a56c2e3d)*

Answer (score 0):

If you have a numbers table that contains tinyints to represent months (and assuming start dates can't be more than 20 years apart), this allocates a single data page:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Months
(
   m tinyint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT dbo.Months SELECT TOP (256) ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
  (ORDER BY [object_id])-1 FROM sys.all_objects 
   ORDER BY [object_id];
```

(You may already have a numbers table of some kind, which is [always a good idea to have around](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11506/1186) - more background [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-1/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4177/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).)

Now you can use CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT m = CONVERT(char(6), DATEADD(MONTH, m.m, p.StartDate), 112)
FROM dbo.ProductTable AS p
CROSS APPLY (SELECT m FROM dbo.Months 
  WHERE m <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.StartDate, p.EndDate)) AS m
WHERE Product_ID = '1' AND Site = 'X';
```

Or a simple join:

```
SELECT m = CONVERT(char(6), DATEADD(MONTH, m.m, p.StartDate), 112)
  FROM dbo.ProductTable AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.Months AS m 
  ON m.m <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.StartDate, p.EndDate)
  WHERE p.Product_ID = '1' AND p.Site = 'X';
```

I'll leave the performance tuning and analysis to you but I'll just share what I observed comparing the initial RCTE, Jeff's fnTally, and the above:

> [image]

Yes, fnTally has fewer total reads, but higher estimates (30% higher, which could affect memory grants at scale), and a higher compile cost. Which of those is more important to you depends on your workload, the size of the product table, the skew in (a) matching rows and (b) max datediff, and your hardware.

Now, you can do this without a recursive CTE, a helper table, or a helper function, but it leads to higher reads:

```
;WITH m(m) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (256) m = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT CONVERT(char(6), DATEADD(MONTH, m.m, p.StartDate), 112)
  FROM dbo.ProductTable AS p
  INNER JOIN m ON m.m <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.StartDate, p.EndDate)
  WHERE Product_ID = '1' AND Site = 'X';
```

You can squeeze those read numbers down by reducing 256 in the TOP clause if you know your datediffs can be < 256 months, but it's hard to get faster than 0. Here are the comparison results:

> [image]

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f32d9069a42ccfce6412a2efadb1080a)

And finally another good resource for number generator functions is [this series from Itzik Ben-Gan](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/05/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-5) (work backward and read all the comments).